# How to switch off NHibernate logging for INFO level?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, log4net

I am using NHibernate & Net Persistence API with C# and MySql db in my project and I have UI layer (ASP.NET), Business Layer, and Data Access Layer (DAL). For logging, I am using log4net.

I have web.config file in my UI layer, and there I have put following lines of code to disable NHibernate INFO level logging:

```
<log4net debug="true">
        <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="Log.txt"/>
            <appendToFile value="true"/>
            <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
            <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="20"/>
            <maximumFileSize value="50MB"/>
            <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
                <level value="WARN"/>
                <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
            </logger>
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>            
        </root>
    </log4net>
```

But it is not working! I can still see INFO level logs, some of the lines from the logs are:

```
INFO  2013-01-09 01:15:06,383  6993ms Environment            lambda_method      - NHibernate 3.2.0.4000 (3.2.0.4000)
INFO  2013-01-09 01:15:06,386  6996ms Environment            lambda_method      - hibernate-configuration section not found in application configuration file
INFO  2013-01-09 01:15:06,387  6997ms Environment            lambda_method      - Bytecode provider name : lcg
INFO  2013-01-09 01:15:06,388  6998ms Environment            lambda_method      - Using reflection optimizer
INFO  2013-01-09 01:15:07,171  7781ms Dialect                lambda_method      - Using dialect: NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO  2013-01-09 01:15:07,390  8000ms Dialect                lambda_method      - Using dialect: NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO  2013-01-09 01:15:07,407  8017ms Mappings               lambda_method      - duplicate import: JDAL.Impl.Entities.EntityName, JDAL, Version=1.0.0.0,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `logger` node is not correct. Try it this way:

```
<root>
   <level value="INFO"/>
   <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>            
</root>
<logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="WARN"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```